# Wordpress 3.3 dog slow when logged in

Tags: performance, wordpress, authentication

**EDIT3**
Boulevard theme was the culprit indeed. An update notifier service runs on every page request for logged in user (one would hope only for admins), which, for some reason takes @10 seconds of limbo-nothing-happening before page all of a sudden loads. This of course affects the logged in user in both admin and public facing screens. Removed the file and voila, snappy page loads all around.

rant: entire day wasted, loss & gain with 3rd party software, arggghhh ;-)

**EDIT2**
Not MySQL either, Boulevard theme seems to be the culprit. How to workaround, I am not sure. Client paid for the theme and wants to use it, but administering the site is a nightmare; i.e. waiting forever for admin screens to load...

**EDIT**
Ok, I confirmed that initial http request arrives instantly at the firewall, logged in or not. However, there is then a 10+ second lagtime before further activity occurs at the firewall layer. I assume that WP sends along the session cookie and then, for reasons TBD, there is a delay in verifying that remote user is logged in.

I'll check MySQL now, assumed with low cpu/memory usage that this would not be a resources issue, but maybe it's a slow query at play...

**ORIGINAL**
What is the deal here?

new to WP, performance is fine when not logged in; however, 10+ seconds to load public or admin screens otherwise.

linux top shows nothing spectacular happening (no spiked cpu, memory usage), so what exactly is WP doing during these 10 pointless seconds? arggghhh ;-)

ajax requests are snappy, so something is happening with normal synchronous http requests that is making WP dog slow (hard to get much done waiting for screens to load, worse than waiting for an application to compile, at least something useful is being done while you wait!)

My semi-workaround is to have Chrome browser window opened, not logged into WP. There are I can view public pages instantly. Then, in Firefox slog away playing the waiting game logged into admin panel ;-(

Clues appreciated, WP impresses (look & feel) but not so much in this respect, madness...

Comment: I've never had a problem with any of my WP sites. Have you got a link to your site? Also, try turning off all plugins to see if its a plugin related problem.

Comment: @marksweb there are no installed plugins. The only addition to a default install is the Boulevard theme. Site is not yet public so cannot share. Again, when not logged in, WP is sufficiently snappy; when logged in, you-gotta-be-kidding me slow...Really not sure what is happening could session cookie passed along with each of the many files that comprise a WP page. Of course, most WP users seem to not be affected, must be something on my end...

Comment: Yeah my only thought is that it must be something in the theme if you've got no plugins. Nothing else would make sense. Can you disable feature of the theme which you might not use?

Comment: @marksweb just checked apache logs for affected site; when not logged in I see file requests (img, css, etc.) processed instantly; on the other hand, when logged in, nothing at all happens for 10 seconds, and then apache shows the files being processed. Now I need to find out what is happening during this 10 second limbo (firewall should shed some light on that end)

Comment: This is an odd one. Never heard anything like it so will have to keep an eye on this.

Comment: looked at query log, yikes, @50 queries are run to process a single WP page, no wonder caching is essential. How one gets around this with login (no-cache) content, I am not sure. Regardless, must be something in my setup, as I assume WP community would be going nuts with 10+ second wait times in a near default setup

Comment: if its in wp-config, remove `define('ENABLE_CACHE', true);` - just read that without it someone halved their queries so its worth testing that. I still think this is theme related though. Have you tried running with a default theme yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Wordpress plugin that implement a cache, turn off cache for a user who is logged in. Wordpress is also known for using a lot a memory. It can slow down the global performance of your web server.

You can monitor the memory used by Wordpress for each page, using [Memory Viewer](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/316-memory-viewer-wordpress-plugin)

Comment: thanks, memory usage is fine as is CPU. Server load is < .10 so clearly not a resources issue. This is a default WP install with no plugins, but am using a custom theme, "Boulevard".

Comment: Is that from Theme Forest? Try switching to a default theme & let us know how it runs. If its the theme forest boulevard it seems to have a lot of plugin type capability included with it's widgets so it depends how that all runs.

Comment: @marksweb it was Boulevard, update-notifier.php service consuming 10 seconds of load time on every page request. Would be nice if there were an option to turn this off at the admin level, only found it by chance glancing through theme directory in ssh session: huh, update-notifier.php what does that do? Oh, there's the cause, and now the solution: "rm -f update-notifier.php". Would prefer, "rm -fr themes/boulevard" but the client wouldn't like that very much ;-)

Comment: I knew it! ;) I should of just posted "it'll be the theme" as my answer originally!! You'll be able to turn that off I'm sure if you just hack through the theme. It'll just be really poorly coded.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I just found this piece of code in update-notifier.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
            $cache = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

TIMEOUT was set to 10 (I guess seconds), edited to 1 sec as above and now while logged in everything works fine...10 seconds is just to big value